# GWT compilation failed - Error - Java ADT

Tags: java, android, gwt

When ever I try to Compile The code to HTML I get the error: GWT compilatiopn failed!

here ist the what ever it is.. http://hastebin.com/latexumowi.rb

Answer (score 0):

> Line 350: No source code is available for type javax.swing.JOptionPane;

it's the use of this class that is crashing the compiler...you can't use java swing compoents on GWT

try this method Window.confirm